# Save state of views in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I develop a HTML 5 app, and have a view where user comments are loaded. It is recursive: any comment can have clickable sub-comments which are loading in the same view and use the same controller.

Everything is OK. But, when I want to go back, comments are loading again, and I lose my position and sub-comments I loaded.

Can I save the state of the view when I go back? I thought I can maybe use some kind of trick, like: append a new view any time I click on sub-comment and hide the previous view. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, instead of loading and keeping state of your UI inside your controllers, you should keep the state in a service. That means, if you are doing this:

```js
app.config(function($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider.when('/', {
   controller: 'MainCtrl'
 }).when('/another', {
   controller: 'SideCtrl'
 });
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.formData = {};   

  $scope./* other scope stuff that deal with with your current page*/

  $http.get(/* init some data */);
});
```

you should change your initialization code to your service, and the state there as well, this way you can keep state between multiple views:

```js
app.factory('State', function(){
  $http.get(/* init once per app */);

  return {
    formData:{},
  };
});

app.config(function($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider.when('/', {
   controller: 'MainCtrl'
 }).when('/another', {
   controller: 'SideCtrl'
 });
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, State){
  $scope.formData = State.formData;   

  $scope./* other scope stuff that deal with with your current page*/
});

app.controller('SideCtrl', function($scope, State){
  $scope.formData = State.formData; // same state from MainCtrl

});

app.directive('myDirective', function(State){
  return {
    controller: function(){
      State.formData; // same state!
    }
  };
});
```

when you go back and forth your views, their state will be preserved, because your service is a singleton, that was initialized when you first injected it in your controller.

There's also the new `ui.router`, that has a state machine, it's a low level version of `$routeProvider` and you can fine grain persist state using `$stateProvider`, but it's currently experimental (and will ship on angular 1.3)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But also, and more important I want to save scrolling position. Because there is long list of comments with dynamically loading, sort of infinity wall. And if controller will be init scroll position will lost.

Comment: save your scroll in your service as well, keep everything that you would, otherwise keep in your controller, in your service. simple as that. it persists between views, controllers and directives. you may even persist it even more by saving it to localStorage/sessionStorage. Like I said, don't do initialization inside your controller, but in your service.

Comment: Does this library solve this? If so, how can it be used for this? If not, why? Thanks! http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky

Answer (score 1):

### Use a Mediator

If you use a *Mediator* you'll be decreasing your *Out-Degree* (*Fan-Out*) by a factor of 2.

**Benefits:**

- You're not coupling your module directly to your server (*$http*).
- You're not coupling your module to an additional service (*State*).
- Everything you need for state-persistence is right there in your controller (*$scope* / *$scope.$on*, *$emit*, *$broadcast*).
- Your Mediator knows more and can direct the application more efficiently.

**Downside(?):**

- Your modules need to fire *interesting* events (*$scope.$emit('list://added/Item', $scope.list.id, item)*)

***mediator.js***

```
angular.module('lists.mediator', ['lists', 'list', 'item']).run(function mediate($rootScope){
    var lists = [];
    $rootScope.lists = lists;
    $rootScope.$watch('lists', yourWatcher, true);
    
    function itemModuleOrControllerStartedHandler(e, itemId, disclose){
        if(!lists.length){
            $http.get(...).success(function(data){
                lists.push.apply(lists, data);
                var item = getItem(lists, itemId);
                disclose(item);  // do not copy object otherwise you'll have to manage changes to stay synchronized
            });
        } else {
            var item = getItem(lists, itemId);
            disclose(item);
        }
    }

    $rootScope.$on('item://started', itemModuleOrControllerStartedHandler);
});

// angular.bootstrap(el, ['lists.mediator'])
```

***item-controller.js***

```
var ItemController = function ItemController($scope, $routeParams){
    var disclosure = $scope.$emit.bind($scope, 'item://received/data', (+new Date()));
    $scope.itemId = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.item = { id: -1, name: 'Nameless :(', quantity: 0 };
    
    function itemDataHandler(e, timestamp, item){
        $scope.item = item;
    }
    
    $scope.$on('item://received/data', itemDataHandler);
    $scope.$emit('item://started', $scope.id, disclosure);
};
```