# Angular : save controller and view state for reload

Tags: angularjs, mobile

I think it is not possible but I want to ask the question to be sure.

I have a controller and an associated view containing a long repeater. When I click on an element of the repeater, I go to a details page.
When I go back, the list page reload.
I use an infinite scroller so the init is quick but if I scroll a lot, when I go back to the list, a lot of items are loaded (in order to return to the same item that was clicked) and as my site is a phone app, the time to generate even 100 elements is quite long on small devices.

So my question is: is it possible to save the state of the controller and the view to just redisplay it without recalculation?

Comment: You can save it in a service. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714409/save-state-of-views-in-angularjs

Comment: No, I don't want the ng-repeat to recalculate. I know how to save my position and how to save the list. But not how to save the entire page

Comment: It would be a little ugly, but if this is an essential optimization perhaps you should load item detail within the same controller, nesting the detail views and making use of ng-show.  You could lazy load the detail views when they are clicked/tapped.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but the user can navigate in sub views from the detail view...

Comment: You can save the scroll height and infinite scroll index in local storage, then load it a second after the page shows when navigated back.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
// On scroll:
     -save scroll height
     -save current greatest index of infinite scroll
// On navigate to page
     -load index of infinite scroll to scroll to
     -load scroll height
     -scroll user down to proper height after last inf-scroll element loads.
```

Comment: Yeah, it is exactly what I do now but the ng-repeat is recreated and it is not what I want. I want to save the html and state in order to avoid the calculation which is time consuming on mobile phone

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading everything save the context in memory and restore it based on some flag , because if you try to reload then, it takes Scroll need to be fired up to that Height, then you have to call the DB for defer scroll , this makes you time delay and  DB hits ......