# Reusing directive with state between pages

Tags: angularjs

I have a few pages in my AngularJS app (using $routeProvider). I created a directive (containing some buttons that allow to set callbacks on them and inputs) that should be reusable between those pages, but the directive uses a service to keep its state when jumping from one page to another.

The problem now is that if you change the state of the directive on first page, the state will be the same on the others, because all of them use the same service. How to decouple this?

The only thing came to my mind is that those directives should have their own ids, like this:

```
<my-directive id="dirOnPageX"></my-directive>
```

so I can store the states in the service according to the id, but this requires me to add id attribute to every directive I put into HTML. Is there any better solution?

Maybe some unique stuff from given directive converted to some hash, and then it would be used as the id? But what, in directive, might be unique and determined?

Comment: Why don't you store the state of the directive in the directive itself instead of the service?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should store the directive state in the scope instead of the service, and use the service to only perform actions

it will allow you to test the directive in isolation as well

hope this helps :)

Comment: bu if I store the state in scope, the scope/directive will be destroyed if I jump to another page, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714409/save-state-of-views-in-angularjs

Comment: well, yes, isn't it what you want to do? if you want to store the data for each time the directive is used it wont be possible without putting an id in as you need to identify that you need to load the data back

Comment: other way would be saving and loading it in the controller using the service, though you still need an id to identify it, if you use only one directive per route you could use that though it would be an obscure piece of logic and could lead to bugs