# how to maintain state across pages in SPA using angular.js

Tags: angularjs

Using a Single Page Architecture, every time the uses goes to a particular page, the controller for that page is run. I need to maintain alot of state across the various SPA pages.

Question: what is the proper way to maintain state across controllers (SPA pages) without polluting the $rootScope?

For some reason, it does not seem "proper" to use a service for managing state.

Thanks,
-Andres

Comment: Look into using ui-router in place of the ngRoute module. It provides functionality that'll save state for you. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: thanks for that tip...I will check out ui-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use Services. Services are singleton objects that can be injected into multiple controllers, that can be used to store state.

Within your state, you can use some kind of caching mechanism like `localStorage`, or `sessionStorage` to maintain persistent storage

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider.when('/', {
   controller: 'MainCtrl'
 }).when('/another', {
   controller: 'SideCtrl'
 });
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, State){
  $scope.formData = State.formData;   

  $scope./* other scope stuff that deal with with your current page*/
});

app.controller('SideCtrl', function($scope, State){
  $scope.formData = State.formData; // same state from MainCtrl

});

app.directive('myDirective', function(State){
  return {
    controller: function(){
      State.formData; // same state!
    }
  };
});
```

Code [courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714409/save-state-of-views-in-angularjs)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I was not sure if using a Service for state was considered a good practice, so your advice is confirmation and much appreciated. I just implemented a Service for my dynamic state and it is working fine. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a good practice to store your state directly inside of $rootScope.

*Why ?*

Because during the digest cycle of angular (dirty checking), rootScope will check that every scope watchers of the application are "stable", this means many, many, many loop inside the DOM to check for modifications and this is really heavy...

However, you can make something better, and you have multiple solutions :

**Solution 1 - Your component/directive tree fits your state tree**

Use higher order directives / components that hold the state and pass the data through child components/directives. This way everything is managed in the parent and you don't have to store anything anywhere else, giving you with stateless components.
Pretty simple solution when your component tree match your state tree.

**Solution 2 - Your component/directive tree doesnt fit your state tree**

You can use angular services to store some kind of information directly inside of them and reuse the state everywhere you need. I don't really like this solution since every services (factory / providers / services) in angularjs are singleton, and it's an anti pattern...

**Solution 3 - Redux**

Redux has been presented (and almost used) by the Reactjs community, but it's not only for React.

You can use it with Angularjs, Angular 2 etc... If your component tree doesn't fit your state tree, I suggest you to take an eye on this library that works pretty well in any frontend javascript project / fw.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have seen the word 'Redux' around a lot but was unaware of what it actually was. I will check it out. Thanks again.