# AngularJS - Keep route component in cache (keep-alive)

Tags: angularjs, angular, components, keep-alive

I need to keep the state of a component A in cache, so that when I navigate from A to B or C and I come back to A it does not get re-render again (it also includes a API call in its constructor, so it's kind of slow). I will like to keep this initial state through out the whole session of the user.
In Vuejs https://jsfiddle.net/shidianxia/ckj7xbqq/ they have a very simple way to do this using this syntax:

```
<keep-alive :include="include">
    <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

I will like to have something similar for AngularJS, notice I say JS so old angular. I have an hybrid application using modern angular but keeping old angularjs router.

I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: There is an stackoverflow.com question which is pretty similar maybe that helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714409/save-state-of-views-in-angularjs

Comment: @PhilippMainz thank you I thought about doing this too. However my main issue is that it takes a lot of time for angular to re-render even after the data has arrived. So with your solution I could solve one part of the problem (limiting request to server to only one) but I will still have to rerender everything.

Answer (score 1):

According you your comment I think it would make sense to build it in 2 parts.

Part 1: Keeping the state in a service
By keeping the state in a service you would limit the request send to the server and thus saving time.

Part 2 Using $templateCache
By using angularjs template cache service you should keep the time for rendering the view with your data to a minimum. You can find infos on how to use that in their docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

If you in the end still have this flicker while rendering you should use ngCloak to prevent showing the uncompiled view (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)